# Float Array into a base64 string in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a Android app in which I want to encode a float array into a base64 string (which I need to pass though the network)

Thanks for the assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun convertToBase64Bytes(floatArray: FloatArray): String? {
    val buff: ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * floatArray.size)
    for (i in floatArray.indices) {
        val amplitude = floatArray[i]
        buff.putFloat(amplitude)
    }
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(buff.array())
}
```